# Get list of deployed webapps in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

How to get the list of webapps deployed in Tomcat using JMX? The URLs are different for various versions of tomcat (eg. in tomcat v6, the URL: "http://:8080/manager/list" will give the list of webapps deployed). The intention is calculate the sum of all activeSessions in Tomcat. We have calculate the sum of each webapp and arrive at the final number.

Comment: the /manager is a web application in tomcat, not a embed module and it could be removed like other web application, you need to search for xml files inside %CATALINA%/conf/Catalina/localhost (just user apps), that each one contains the docBase refers to the web app base code, also %CATALINA%/webapps contains pre installed apps, such as /manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for us:

```
Set<ObjectName> names = mbeanServer.queryNames(new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Host,*"), null);
Set<String> hostNames = new HashSet<String>();
for (ObjectName on : names) {
    hostNames.add(on.getKeyProperty("host"));
}
for (String str : hostNames) {
    ObjectName[] webapps = (ObjectName[]) mbeanServer.getAttribute(new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Host,host=" + str), "children");
    for (ObjectName ob : webapps) {
        String[] appSpl = ob.getKeyProperty("name").split("//localhost");
        webappNames.add(appSpl[1]);
    }
}
```